# Formula to calculate the average diameter of a mixture of two sizes of marbles.

Tags: physics, word-problem, chemistry

Im looking to mix two particle sizes of powder metals, and need to calculate the resultant average particle size.

O.K. More specifically:  I mix 50 pounds of metal powder that has a spherical particle size of 6 microns with 50 pounds of metal powder that has a spherical particle size of 0.8 micron.  What is the resultant average particle size?  All have the same density.  By volume, 1 large particle is 419 times larger than a small particle, so there are 419 times more small particles than large particles. D(avg) = .5D(1) + .5D(2) does not work.  The mixture is much finer because of the large size difference between the two particle sizes. I need to know the average particle size.

Comment: Do you mean: what is the expected diameter of a randomly chosen particle (particles are chosen with equal probability, regardless of diamater)? In this case, the average you want is simply the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of the two particle diameters ...

Comment: You should clarify what you mean to ask! I've voted to close the question since it's unclear at the moment.

Comment: It sounds somewhat like a "balls in an urn" problem except the goal is not to find a probability. Rather you draw out, let is say, 1000 balls at random and $40$% have diameter $d_1$ and $60$% have diameter $d_2$, what is the average diameter? Then $d_{avg}=0.4\,d_1+0.6\,d_2$. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: On the other hand if what you really want to know is what will be the volume of a certain quantity of the mixture, then it depends on the **relative** sizes of the particles, not on their average size and becomes a difficult sphere packing problem.